# Searching and returning a value using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a program to scan videos, find what languages the audio and subtitles are available in, and then use those findings for input.

Currently, I'm generating the output with this:

```
with open('output.txt', 'wt') as output_f:
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=output_f, stderr=output_f)
```

Here's the bit of text from my scan that I need.

```
  + audio tracks:
    + 1, Japanese (aac) (2.0 ch) (iso639-2: jpn)
  + subtitle tracks:
    + 1, English (iso639-2: eng) (Text)(SSA)
```

So I need to find out what number is in front of Japanese, but only after it comes after "audio tracks"

Similarly, I need to find what number is in front of English, but only after it comes after "subtitle tracks"

I'm pretty sure I need to use Regular Expressions to do this, but I'm lost on where to begin.

Comment: Why the `subprocess` call?

Comment: You need to do this in 2 steps: pick out the part of text that show the audio/video tracks with regex, then do a second pass on the smaller part of text to extract information.

Comment: Japanese and English are just examples right? You actually want to find the number in front of the language but after `audio tracks:` and `subtitle tracks:`. This shouldn't be a problem, you simply have to do a lookbehind for `audio tracks` or `subtitle tracks` or use some groups.

Comment: Subprocess is called because of the way I'm executing the command.

No, I need the Japanese language for Audio (or Undefined as the case is sometimes) and I need the English subtitles. The problem stems from the issue of having dual audio and multiple subtitles on some vidoes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a regex here - anyway it seems too complicated to use one of those for me too.

Here's some regular parsing:

```
with open('output.txt', 'wt') as output_f:
    parseTracks = False
    lines = tuple(output_f)
    for line in lines:
        if 'audio tracks' in line:
            parseTracks = True
        if parseTracks:
            if 'Japanese' in line:
                theNumber = int(''.join([char for char in line if char in '1234567890']))
```

Same thing with the subtitles.

Comment: Replace `char in '123456789'` with `char.isdigit()` Also you will take too many digits and so it's still wrong.

Comment: So when I run this code I get the following error:

    lines = tuple(output_f)
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Answer (score 0):

This will work (use with .findall()):

```
(?<=subtitle tracks:\n)\s+\+\s(\d+)
(?<=audio tracks:\n)\s+\+\s(\d+)
```

Check for a certain prefix (include the newline), then consume the white space and select numbers after a '+'

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> audio_regex = re.compile(r'\+ audio tracks:\n\s*\+ (?P<number>\d+), (?P<lang>\w+)')
>>> subtitle_regex = re.compile(r'\+ subtitle tracks:\n\s*\+ (?P<number>\d+), (?P<lang>\w+)')
>>> text = '''
...   + audio tracks:
...     + 1, Japanese (aac) (2.0 ch) (iso639-2: jpn)
...   + subtitle tracks:
...     + 1, English (iso639-2: eng) (Text)(SSA)
... '''
>>> match = audio_regex.search(text)  #find the first match
>>> match.group('number')
'1'
>>> match.group('lang')
'Japanese'
>>> audio_regex.findall(text)   #find all matches
[('1', 'Japanese')]
>>> subtitle_regex.findall(text)
[('1', 'English')]
```

Tweak the regexes above to be more or less flexible depending on the format of your file(e.g. if instead of a single space you could have more spaces you can replace the spaces with `\s+` to match one or more space.